# Is it possible to install a ringtone on an iPhone using Garageband?

Tags: iphone, ios, garageband

Can a custom ringtone be created or installed on an iPhone using the GarageBand app from Apple on the iPhone?  (and without using a Mac or PC, and without buying the ringtone using the Music App).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open the Garageband app on the iPhone
2. Tap the [+] button to create a new song, select your instruments to use, and get ready to play around or just press buttons
3. When satisfied with your tone jingle idea, record the audio by tapping on the red Record button, then tapping it again to stop the recording
4. Tap the downward pointing arrow icon in the corner and choose “My Songs”
5. Select the song you just created and choose the Sharing icon in the corner, it looks like a box with an arrow pointing out of it
6. Choose “Ringtone” from the sharing options
7. Name the ringtone whatever you would like and assign the artist name, song name, etc (this is basically the metadata for the Garageband song, which will be embedded in the ringtone) then tap on “Export”
8. Choose one of three options depending on what you want to do with the newly created ringtone:

   - Standard Ringtone – this assigns the ringtone as your new default ringtone for all incoming calls
   - Standard Text Tone – this assigns the ringtone as the new default
     text tone for all incoming text messages and iMessages
   - Assign to Contact – this assigns the ringtone specifically to a
     designated contact in your address book only playing when that
     individual contacts you
9. When finished, exit out of Garageband as usual and enjoy your newly created ringtone or text tone.

For images and further information, visit the source: [OSXDaily](http://osxdaily.com/2015/01/12/create-ringtone-iphone-garageband/)